# external linked variable initialized multiple times

Tags: c++, gcc, external-links

I have a little synthetic example that have behaviour I want to change, but don't quite know how.

What I have is this:

1. Common header **statich.h** that have external declaration of some variable:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   struct S {
     S() : x(42) { 
       std::cout << "S(), this=" << this << std::endl;
     }
     ~S() { 
       std::cout << "~S(), this=" << this << std::endl;
     }
     int x;
   };

   extern S nakedS;
   ```
2. Static library **libstatic.a** compiled from source file **statich.cpp**, that have definition of that external variable:

   ```
   #include "statich.h"

   S nakedS;
   ```
3. Dynamic library **libdyn.so** compiled from source file **dyn.cpp** and linking with **libstatic.a**. Here's source code:

   ```
   #include "statich.h"

   void foo() {
     std::cout << "I'm foo() from dyn! nakedS.x == " << nakedS.x << std::endl;
   }
   ```
4. Executable **supertest** that compiled from source file **main.cpp** and linking with both of libraries, static and shared. Here's source code:

   ```
   #include "statich.h"
   int main() {
     std::cout << "nakedS.x == " << nakedS.x << std::endl;
   }
   ```
5. I have **CMakeLists.txt** file that build all that stuff for me. Here it is:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
     "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC"    
   )

   add_library( static STATIC "statich.cpp" )

   add_library( dyn SHARED "dyn.cpp" )
   target_link_libraries( dyn static )

   add_executable( supertest main.cpp )

   set(DEPS
     static
     dyn
   )

   target_link_libraries( supertest ${DEPS} )
   ```

Point is, when I run `cmake . && make && ./supertest` I got this output:

```
S(), this=0x6012c4
S(), this=0x6012c4
nakedS.x == 42
~S(), this=0x6012c4
~S(), this=0x6012c4
```

Which means double initialization of same object, that is not what I want at all. Can I change this behaviour *without replacing* **libdyn.so** with static analogue? Maybe, some compiler/linker flags? What should I read to learn more about it? Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I got this behaviour on my specific compiler version:
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC)

On other machine where I have diffirent compiler:
gcc version 4.6.4 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.4-1ubuntu1~12.04)
All works fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. To work it around, you could define your variable as weak, e.g.

```
#include "statich.h"

__attribute__((weak)) S nakedS;
```

Comment: That works for me, thanks. Am I right that this approach is GCC-specific? If so, is there any portable way to have same effect?

Comment: GCC/ELF specific, so mingw don't support it. Clang do, though (on ELF based systems). I know no portable way; generally speaking, this approach should be avoided (mostly because of quite weird logic rather than system support).